# Unable to make query to OrientDB using Orientjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, orientdb

I am trying to connect to OriendDB(v2.0.13) using Orientjs(v2.0.0) on NodeJS(v0.12.2) like so:

```
var OrientDB = require('orientjs');

var orientDBServer = OrientDB({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 2424,
  username: 'orientdb',
  password: 'orientdb'
});

var database = orientDBServer.use({
    name: 'thermos',
    username: 'orientdb',
    password: 'orientdb'
});
```

As soon as I make a query, for example:

```
database.select().from('OUser').all()
.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

I'm getting this error.

> Unhandled rejection OrientDB.ConnectionError [1]: Remote server closed
>   the connection.
>       at Connection.handleSocketEnd (/usr/share/adafruit/webide/repositories/my-pi-projects/Thermostat/node_modules/orientjs/lib/transport/binary/connection.js:320:9)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:104:17)
>       at _stream_readable.js:908:16
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

I tried different query just to make sure I'm not doing a mistake myself and I also tried via studio and the console directly on the server which worked fine. (using the same logins...)

What can possibly cause this error? 
Thanks

**Update**
I made a second nodejs server and now I can successully make requests on the database that is installed on the first server. I'll investigate if there is some sort of weird permission that blocks localhost or if node is missing some kind of permission...(first server is running raspbian)

Comment: Have you tried using 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have to specify the username and password again for the use function. My database config file looks like this and it works like a charm :

```
var OrientDB = require('orientjs');

var server = OrientDB({
    host:'localhost',
    port:2424,
    username: 'root',
    password: 'root'
});

module.exports = server.use('databaseName');
```

Also, make sure that you created the database with the account you are using. Otherwise, it won't work.

If this still doesn't work, it could be a bug. I would personally try recreating the database...

Comment: I still get the same issue when I try it like you suggested.

Comment: Added something after my configuration. Updated  my answer. Does it work now ?

Comment: thanks for the help; Same error again using your updated answer... the username and password are correct, I'm using the same to connect via the console and I can make queries without issues..

Comment: Maybe something wen't terribly wrong. Can you try recreating another dummy database with the right credentials and test it ? Tell me if it works.

Comment: I used the console instead of the website and typed this: "CREATE DATABASE remote:localhost/stackoverflow orientdb orientdb plocal". successfully created the DB and logged onto it. I changed my "use" command in my script and I got again the same error as before. :\

Answer (score 0):

After days of running in circles I finally found that if I remove another library that I am using, everything works fine... (library causing the conflict is GrovePi). I'll continue investigating to find the root of the issue. Thanks for your help Alex.